# Redirect To Page Besides Default After User Logs In

Tags: asp.net, templates, visual-studio-2012, authentication

I am using Visual Studio 2012, and created a project using the "ASP.NET Web Forms App" (Not the empty project). The project handles creating new logins, and changing passwords by default. After a user logs in, they are redirected to the default page. How do I change what page a user is redirected to once they are logged in?

This way is great to redirect all users:

```
<asp:Login runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled" RenderOuterTable="false" OnLoggedIn="Log_LoggedIn" ID="Log">
```

I would like to redirect each user to a different page. I can't figure out the syntax to get this to work the way that I want it.

```
public partial class Login : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Page.User != null && this.Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (this.Page.User.Identity.Name.Equals("me")) this.Response.Redirect("~/somepage");
            else this.Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
        }
        else this.Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login.aspx");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out some code to get that I wanted to do done. I wanted to redirect the user page if the user matched a certain name:

```
var Username = Page.User.Identity.Name;
        if (Username == "me")
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/somepage");
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Find this entry in `web.config` (configuration/system.web/authentication/):

```
<forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/" />
```

And set `defaultUrl` to what ever page you wish.

To change login behaviour:

Find this in /Account/Login.aspx

```
<asp:Login runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled" RenderOuterTable="false"...
```

change to...

```
 <asp:Login runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled" RenderOuterTable="false" OnLoggedIn="Log_LoggedIn" ID="Log">
```

Add handler in code behind (/Account/Login.aspx.cs)

```
    protected void Log_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("/wherever");
    }
```

Comment: How would I do this per user?

Comment: Hook `OnLoggedIn` event on the Login control on Account/Login.aspx. You can redirect there depending on what exactly you require

Comment: When you say hook OnLoggedIn. What do you mean, can you be more descriptive please.

Comment: That is helping a lot thanks. I am still having trouble getting the syntax for the individual user. The code above will redirect anyone.

Comment: if (this.Page.User != null && this.Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (this.Page.User.Identity.Name.Equals("Admin"))
                this.Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Default.aspx");
            else
                this.Response.Redirect("~/Member/Default.aspx");
        }
        else this.Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");

Comment: @nate please update your original question, or raise a new question with your latest issue

Comment: I did update my original question before you posted your last comment, do I need to revise it some more?

Comment: I see you have posted your answer to the last part of your question. If your question is answered then please mark as so